# Angular throw error no provider for InjectionToken although component has provides

Tags: angular

I want to get an instance of Bar (`InjectionToken`):

```
import { inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const Bar = new InjectionToken<string>('bar');

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FooService {
  bar = inject(Bar);

  getSome() {
    console.log({ bar: this.bar });
  }
}
```

which is provided in the component:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Bar, FooService } from './foo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `in app`,
  standalone: true,
  providers: [{ provide: Bar, useValue: 'blabla' }],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {}

  some() {
    this.fooService.getSome();
  }
}
```

But angular throws errors:

```
No provider for InjectionToken bar!
```

Why? I initial the `InjectionToken` in the component.
What I can do to solve this problem?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fwxwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Let try
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jx3ex9?file=src/app/foo.service.ts

The angular throws errors because in FooService you defined
bar = inject(Bar);
Runtime, the angular create new instance of FooService => is no provider for the InjectionToken bar!